# Is there any way to get the global variable gDVM in Android native code?

Tags: android, native

I wonder if there is any way to get the global variable gDVM of the DvmGlobals data structure in Android native code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to this file: http://osxr.org/android/source/dalvik/vm/Globals.h

The variable gDvm is declared as **exported**, which means that as soon as you include the library Globals.h in your native code, you should be able to get access to its methods and attributes by simple using the variable gDvm as follows:

`JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_test_debugging_DebuggerConnectedJNI(JNIenv * env, jobject obj) {
    if (gDvm.debuggerConnect || gDvm.debuggerAlive)
        return JNI_TRUE;
    return JNI_FALSE;
}`